# SQL Server : CASE statement multiplication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue with this line of code.

I'm trying to calculate or multiply numbers from .01 to .04 by .25 and anything above .04 is multiplied by 1. It works when I multiply a number higher that .04 for example .05 it multiplies it by .01 but anything below .05 does not get multiplied by .25. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Here's the what I have:

This is the new one

```
CASE WHEN curOther IS  THEN curOther + .01 ELSE (curOther * .25) + curOther END
```

This is the original

```
CASE WHEN curOther > .04 then .01 ELSE curOther * .25 + curOther END
```

Comment: Why are you adding .01 in your `Case` statement if you only intend to multiply it?

Comment: I assume what you're looking for is something like this: `Case When curOther > 0.4 Then curOther * 0.01 Else curOther * 0.25 End`

Comment: Its because I'm trying to calculate 401k rates. If an employees rate is less than or equal to .04 than it needs to be multiplied by .25, but if the employees rate is grater than .04 the rate needs to be multiplied by .01

Comment: What is your intent when curOther < 0.01?  Also, what is the data type for curOther?  Is it a fixed-width decimal?  Is it a floating-point?  These might affect your result.  Finally, it might help if you provided some sample input data (a small handful of entries) and expected results.  I am having trouble matching your question to the case-statements you present.

Comment: Rate needs to be multiplied by .01 and added to the rate

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN curOther <= .04 THEN curOther*1.01 ELSE curOther*1.25 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing two different things in your original CASE statement.

### Starting Point

Your "original" statement is this:

```
CASE WHEN curOther > .04 then .01 ELSE curOther * .25 + curOther END
```

This will return one of two values:

```
.01
(curOther * .25) + curOther
```

Given a starting curOther value of 10.0, this returns either:

```
.01
12.50
```

### First Possibility

You actually want the CASE statement to return:

```
10.10 
12.50
```

In this scenario, your CASE statement ought to be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN curOther > .04 
    THEN (curOther * .01) + curOther 
    ELSE (curOther * .25) + curOther 
  END
```

Which could be further simplified to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN curOther > .04 
    THEN curOther * 1.01 
    ELSE curOther * 1.25
  END
```

### Second Possibility

You actually want the CASE statement to return:

```
1.01 
1.25
```

After doing so, you will then multiply your other value by this value (`curOther * {CASE}`), resulting in:

```
10.10 
12.50
```

If so, your CASE statement should be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN curOther > .04 
    THEN 1.01 
    ELSE 1.25
  END
```

### Third Possibility

You are trying to return the multiplier by which this will increase:

```
.01
.25
```

Given a starting curOther value of 10.0, you will do something like:

```
(curOther * {CASE}) + curOther
```

This will give you:

```
10.10 
12.50
```

In which scenario, you should use:

```
CASE 
    WHEN curOther > .04 
    THEN .01 
    ELSE .25
  END
```